# How to manage large data set driven tests in test automation?

Tags: git, testing, automated-tests

We have our test framework code base along with test data set on git repo. 
Test data size is huge and will vary from 1 GB to 20 GB and git is not a solution to store such data. Time-consuming tasks are:

- Download data from source (Git)
- Transfer data to target test machine.

What shall be the solution to reduce data transfer time?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it makes no sense to transfer such huge files between machines for each test execution cycle. Especially if all the files are static, and builds' frequency is high.

Depending on available resources / infrastructure I'd consider using Docker images or VMs with shared folders. For example, in case of Docker you could have a mounted volume with test data. VMs could be configured to use host's share as well (or just deploy it with already injected custom data). Public services also provide such features.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for the proposed solution what data transfer time shall we expect for per GB.

Comment: With docker it'll be be the same file system (linux host will map volume with a container), so I don't believe you'll see any performance degradation at all.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that requires least of storage is dynamic data generation. Instead of having hardcoded values and files you may be able to create algorithms to generate those.

If dynamic data is not an option, you can store files in Maven repo (Sonatype Nexus) and download those files. Such files would have a version and Maven is smart enough not to download artifacts if they are already downloaded.

Such huge amounts of data would require a lot of storage if you change it often. So Nexus machine would need to be pretty large.